# Query data from MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I work on my BAC project. I must opening and closing a door in funtion of time selected on a website. Time are sent into a mysql server.

Here it’s my structure of my DB : 
[MySQL database on PHPmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjYiS.png)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
import time
import datetime
import threading
import MySQLdb


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.OUT)

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                    user="root",         # your username
                   passwd="Orel_27130",  # your password
                    db="projet")        # name of the data base

        #Identification Twilio
account_sid = "AC6aa155119de0e74e188148e3de6a92dd" # Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "2a94f22a7a60709f340230c5846d3a06"  # Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)                  


day = datetime.datetime.now()
day = day.isoweekday()


if day == 3 :
    while day == 3:
        # calcul du time delta + affichage de l'heure actuelle au format H24
        midnight = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.min)
        now_relative = datetime.datetime.now() - midnight
        print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

        # Requete SQL
        cursor1 = db.cursor()
        cursor1.execute("SELECT time_open FROM time WHERE id = 3")
        time_open = cursor1.fetchone()
        cursor2 = db.cursor()
        cursor2.execute("SELECT time_close FROM time WHERE id = 3")
        time_close = cursor2.fetchone()


        # Si Time open est superieur ou egale a l'heure actuelle et si time close est inferieur a l'heure actuelle
        if(time_open[0] >= now_relative and time_close[0] < now_relative):
            print ("Fermee")
            GPIO.output(38, False)
            GPIO.output(40, True)   
        else:
            print ("Ouvert")
            GPIO.output(38, True)
            GPIO.output(40, False)
```

Why when I change the Time_close value, nothing change and when I change Time_Open, the condition works, please ??

Thank's

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: My question is why when I change the Time_close value, nothing change and when I change Time_Open, the condition works

Comment: Please add your question the THE QUESTION AREA and not to the comments section.